# SQL Server: Select while combining start/stop records within X minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables:

Master

```
 Id   INT IDENTITY
 Day  DATETIME
 User INT
```

Detail

```
 Id         INT IDENTITY
 Fk_Id      INT           ( << foreign Key to Master Id )
 UsageStart DATETIME
 UsageStop  DATETIME
```

For all users, for days within a given range, I would like to return the following activity for a given week:

```
 User, Day, UsageStart, UsageStop
```

However, where the user stopped and then started usage again within 10 minutes, I need to combine these records. For example. The following:

```
  User, Day, UsageStart, UsageStop
  199   Tue  14:55       15:25
  199   Tue  15:25       15:27
  199   Tue  15:32       15:45 
  199   Tue  18:12       18:16
```

I need to display the following (merging the first three records):

```
  User, Day, UsageStart, UsageStop
  199   Tue  14:55       15:45
  199   Tue  18:12       18:16
```

I know how to find the records that would be affected using a query similar to below:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.Detail d 
  WHERE fk_Id in (SELECT Id
                    FROM Master
                   WHERE Day between '1/1/18' and '1/5/18')  
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM Detail d2 
                WHERE d2.Fk_Id = d.Fk_Id 
                  and d.Id <> d2.Id 
                  and datediff(MINUTE,d.UsageStop,d2.UsageStart) < 10)
```

But I'm not sure about the optimal way of actually creating the query to display the request (combining results within 10 minutes. Is there a simple/efficient way of doing this that I'm not seeing? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Use the `LAG()` function to peek into the previous rows (ordered by date/time) and to determine if they correspond to the same or different session.

Comment: Google `SQL Gaps and Islands Problem`, this is a common question.

Answer (score 0):

Use lag to get the previous record, then use logic to determine where the groups start, and a cumulative sum to assign the group.  Then, aggregation:

```
select usr, min(usage_start), max(usage_stop)
from (select d.*, 
             sum(case when prev_us >= dateadd(minute, -10, usage_start) 
                      then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user order by usage_start) as grp
      from (select d.*,
                   lag(usage_stop) over (partition by user order by usage_start) as prev_us
            from detail d
           ) d
     ) d
group by user, grp;
```